# How write a regex starts and ends with particular string?

Tags: regex

I hava a string, like this:

`{"content":(uint32)123", "id":(uint64)111, "test":{"hi":"(uint32)456"}}`

I want to get result:

```
(uint32)123
(uint64)111
```

so I write regex like this:

```
[^(?!\")](\(uint32\)|\(uint64\))(\d)+[^(?!\")$]
```

but the result is:

```
:(uint32)123
:(uint64)111,
```

here the result adds `:` and `,`

I hope that the regex does not begin with `"` and does not end with `"` , now I should how change my regex?

Comment: You say it _does not end with `"`_, but your string has a `"` after `123`. Eliminate this contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

`(\(uint(?:32|64)\)\d+)` Works for me.  It captures the entire string `(uint[32/64])<any number of digits\>` without bothering about the characters that come before or after.

Answer (score 0):

It looked like you was trying to use negative lookahead and negative lookbehind checks. But you did couple of mistakes:

1. You put them inside symbol group like this: `[^(?!\")]` what this regexp really mean - not any of symbols inside square bracket (^ - stands for not). How it should be instead: `(?!\")` - which mean symbol after current position shouldn't be quote (note: this will also work if there is no symbol after
2. To check symbol before you need to use look ahead check which have syntax `(?<!some_regexp)`. So it would be `(?<!\")`
3. You don't need checks for start or end of the line. If you do you can put then into separate negative look ahead/behind statement.

Here is corrected example without line start/end checks:

```
(?<!\")(\(uint32\)|\(uint64\))(\d)+(?!\")(?!\d)
```

Note: you need to add (?!\d) at the end, cause otherwise it would match everything except last digit if there is quote.

Here is example with start/end of line checks:

```
(?<!^)(?<!\")(\(uint32\)|\(uint64\))(\d)+(?!\")(?!\d)(?!$)
```

P.S.: depending on language you using - you might not need to escape quote - you do need to escape quote only in case it is string escape sequence not regexp escape sequence.

Comment: hi, Dmitry, I have changed my hope result.

Comment: @thinkerou That shouldn't change regexp. Wasn't it working?

Comment: If your regex like this `(?!\")(\(uint32\)|\(uint64\))(\d)+(?!\")(?!\d)`, it is OK, the result is `(uint64)111`.

Comment: It should starts with (?<!\") not (?!\") to check symbol before. ALthough it might be that your language doesn't support this construction(javascript for instances doesn't). What are you using for regexps?

Comment: Using python. `a = '{"content":(uint32)123", "id":(uint64)111, "test":{"hi":"(uint32)456"}}'` `p = re.compile(r'(?<!\")(\(uint32\)|\(uint64\))(\d)+(?!\")(?!\d)')` `p.findall(a)` , result: `[('(uint64)', '1')]`

Answer (score 0):

Tested the following one in python

```
(?<!\")(\(uint32\)|\(uint64\))\d+(?!(\"|\d))
```